# Light goes through non-transparent object?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, light, emission

Hello fellow Blender artists!

A friend of mine has designed this piece of a cyberpunk, sci-fi, post-apocalypse underground colony in a world with no sun, and he asked me to make a simple 3D model to use as a reference for drawing lights and shadows. (Beware the model is cut in half, in order to get a view of the underground)

As seen in the pictures below, there is part of a sphere on the ground. It's my understanding, that it's some kind of forcefield that's also emitting light (since there's no sun), but I have a problem with the glow-effect reaching underground floors due to the model being cut in half, but that obviously isn't what I want it to do.
As you can see in the picture below, the glow shouldn't go under the white line:

[image]

In an attempt to fix this issue, I've added a plane surface at ground level, so that lights shouldn't be able to pass through to the underground levels. This might not be the best way to fix it, but the final project is to be rendered in orthographic view, so the plane won't be visible.
You can see the plane in the picture below.

[image]

Now, when I render the scene, I would expect the glow effect to stop spreading at the plane (ground level), but as you can see in the rendered picture below, the glow still reaches underneath the ground.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how physics work?
How can I fix this?

Please keep in mind that I'm far from professional, so I'd appreciate it if you could explain your solutions in detail. Thanks.

Edit: .blend-file upload:
[image]

Edit: Update for Chris:

[image]

Comment: If you are using EEVEE, the results will not be realistic. Also, the lighter part on the floor’s walls may not be from the gloWbe, but rather a speculative reflection of a nearby light. Also, beware that the world background does illuminate things.

Comment: The glow although maybe not perfectly realistic simulates some overblowing due to very bright light, which like lens flares usually is happening in camera lenses or on sensors (don't punch me for physical details). So the glow you see is not light shining onto the levels below, but overbright light radiating across its physical boundaries. Okay this sounds stupid because I'm not going to explain it physically correct. If you just deactivate the glow you will see that there's no light shining down (at least if the light is not overlapping the geometry somewhere).

Comment: I think you're right Gordon Brinkmann, the problem might very well be the light reflecting in the camera lens.

Comment: Then we have been misunderstanding each other... Now I've updated the pic from earlier. I wanted the light from the sun to make the underground visible, The only light that is bothering me is the glow emitted by the sphere. As you can see in the updated pic, I've drawn a red square at the bottom... It's clearly visible, that the glow infiltrates this area, but it shouldn't... In other words, with the sun disabled, everything within the square should be pitch black.